# What .NET method has this error message: "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types"

Tags: .net

What .NET method has this error message: "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types"

The stack traces have been stipped from my logs so I'm looking for a starting point.

Answers:

- `Convert.ToInt32`: "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types."
- VB's `CInt`: "Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid."
- C#'s `(int)`: "Specified cast is not valid."
- `Int32.Parse(x.ToString())`: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: All of them.  It's an exception raised by an assignment.

Comment: Not true. I have identified four different error messages for improperly casting/converting an DBNull to a Int32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a Convert.To_ method or something similar, but I don't know that that will give you much insight into finding it. This error is raised when you're trying to use a value you got from a database (and it's null), though, so I would start by looking at where you're getting your data from.

Comment: Yes, Reflector shows, that this messages comes out of the `System.Convert` class (at least that is one of the places'). The message text is stored in the resources of mscorlib.dll

Comment: Yep, that was the one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're attempting to pull data from a DataReader/DataTable/ResultSet and bind it to a text field or web control item.

Typically you need to test for IsDBNull before doing those kind of binding, or you'll get the error message specified.

Comment: I know I'm supposed to check for nulls. What I was asking is which conversion/casting method had that particular message so that I could find the errant code and fix it.